# How to insert the values in page pdf with itext pdf

Tags: java, iterator, itext

I tried to insert values into the pdf like this :

```
String nomeArquivo ="tempRelatorioPDF.pdf";
File file = new File(nomeArquivo);
file.createNewFile();

PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(file)); 
doc.open();     
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new `FileOutputStream(nomeArquivo));`
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());

while(iteratorRow.hasNext()){
   Object valorCelulaRow = iteratorRow.next();

    Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph(); 
    p3.add(colunas[i].getName());
    p3.add("\n"); 
    doc.add((com.itextpdf.text.Element)p3); 

    if(valorCelulaRow != null){

       Paragraph p = new Paragraph(valorCelulaRow.toString());
       doc.add(p); 
}
doc.close();
```

**Displays the error:** **PDF FILE IS CORRUPT** actually gives error opening the file appears to be corrupt.

**

### ADJUSTMENTS PRIOR TO GET TO THIS POINT

**
**I use the following libraries for this:**

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.ListItem;

*>>>>> import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;*

...
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;

*>>>>> import com.lowagie.text.Document;*

import com.lowagie.text.Element;
import com.lowagie.text.Font;
...
```

There is a conlito when retreat commented library and additio the itext. the doc.Add in error.

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document; 
// import com.lowagie.text.Document;
```

**ERROR After the change of import reference**

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());      

//The constructor Document(Rectangle) is undefined

PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(file)); 

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(nomeArquivo));
//The method getInstance(Document, OutputStream) in the type PdfWriter is not applicable for the arguments (Document, FileOutputStream)
```

**[partially solved]**

Add the "(com.itextpdf.text.Element)"

change "Add" for "add";

The debug data is loaded into the variable 'p' and 'P3'. But the PDF document is generated with 0kb.

Comment: You should open your document with `doc.open();` before adding content to it and close it at the end with `doc.close();`.

Comment: Thanks xyres. I'm having trouble with my browser to edit. It did not work for any of the add.doc lines displays the following error:
'com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph can not be cast to com.lowagie.text.Element ".

For me the code seems correct, I researched the meaning of the error, and I ecredito not be compatible with the cause. Even without the kind of modifier "(Element)", the code does not.

Comment: hi Denis Colliot. I close the document after this iterator block. but I just put the fragemento this code

Comment: The ClassCastException implies that you have two different versions of iText on your classpath. Which version of iText do you use?

Comment: I'm remove the references the lines error for "PDFWriter" and modify The document type, removing the type document page. Now:   
     Document doc = new Document();

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I'm not sure how it would not. I don't think you should be casting anything. [Paragraph](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/) allows for direct construction using a String parameter. I take it you want the paragraph to have value of `valueCellRow.toString()` correct?

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
while(iteratorRow.hasNext()) {
    Object valorCelulaRow = iteratorRow.next();
    if(valorCelulaRow != null) {
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(valueCellRow.toString());
        doc.Add (p);
    }
}
doc.close();
```

If all else fails, it's your libraries (*com.lowagie.text.Element* **vs** *com.itextpdf.text.Element*) clashing. Try use:

`doc.Add((com.itextpdf.text.Element) p);`

Though you shouldn't need to.

Comment: After the change suggested by you. there is an error in the "doc.Add (p)". "The method Add (Paragraph) is undefined for the Document type"

Comment: `Document` might be referencing the wrong library as well. Try `com.itextpdf.text.Document` ? More info at [Document](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/index.html?com/itextpdf/text/Document.html). Trust me the API for libraries like these are GODSENT.

Comment: nsidesin. I modified the Document libraries. But now the pdf document is loaded blank. I did debug and data are carregos being the repetition of lace and added correctly. which can cusar the problem of not load the information in PDF. It is loaded all the time, not the blank page of the pdf I visualize.